# Testing a negative flow in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Issue:-** webelement (Button) isdisplayed() doesn't works for negative scenarios

**Requirement:-** I need to fail a test flow in case a button is not displayed on the screen and if its present, then proceed with the flow

**Code:-**

```
if (driver.findElement(By.id("button")).isDisplayed() == false) {
System.out.println("The Button isn't present. Exiting!!");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
}
else
{
//Proceed with the positive flow
}
```

In above code, if the button is not present at all on the screen, the test should fail (if statement should be executed, but it's not)

Comment: can you post the html for the button? Also are you sure there is only one such button on the page?

Comment: Yes, there's only 1 button of this id (sound's weird but of all the buttons, 1 button has an id of 'button')

Answer (score 2):

As TestAutomationEngr has mentioned, make sure there is only one type of such button on the page...

one more way you could test for negative flow in webdriver is by using a **try and catch**..

In your case,

```
boolean buttonFound=false;
try
{ 
    new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("button")));

    buttonFound=true;

}catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("The Button isn't present. Exiting!!");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout")).click();
}

if(buttonFound)
{
  //positive flow
}
```

here it'l wait for 10 secs for visibility of element,

- **if found,** `buttonFound` is set to true,hence positive flow is executed
- **if not found,** the message in catch clause will be displayed and logout link will be clicked

Comment: The issue with above approach is in case of positive flow, if the code breaks at any point it will go to the catch block and pass the test case even when the test case is failing.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it is not required to logout in case an exception is thrown because when the driver is closed this session will be lost. The following code will fail the test in case the element is not present or it is not enabled.

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));
Assert.assertTrue(elem.isEnabled());
```

At the end you just need to close the driver in the test teardown the

```
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FindElements.Count approach.

Like this:

```
    public bool IsElementDisplayed(IWebDriver driver, By element)
    {
        if (driver.FindElements(element).Count > 0)
        {
            if (driver.FindElement(element).Displayed)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.